# Using VideoTexture.ImageRender to get camera image

Tags: python, game-engine

I am currently building a simulator using the Blender Game Engine. I got stuck at the point where I need to extract the camera image from the virtual camera.

I've found the VideoTexture.ImageRender class but this class does not provide any image.

The code I am using is the following:

```
import GameLogic
import VideoTexture

scene = GameLogic.getCurrentScene()
cam = scene.active_camera

imageRender = VideoTexture.ImageRender(scene, cam)

imageRender.refresh()

if(imageRender.valid):
    print(imageRender.image)
else:
    print("No image available")
```

The output imageRender.image is always `None`. Am I missing something? Anyone knows where the problem might be?

Thank you very much for  your help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. I looked into the source code of Blender and it seems that ImageRender only works when rendering to a texture and it is not the currently active camera.

What I did was to add an additional plane, create a material along with a texture rendered it to that plane. After that, I was able to store the image.

In addition to that, I set the new camera as the active camera for the scene. Hope that this answer will help other people.